# Laravel 5.5 : Last Login and Last Login IP are not to be updating on successful login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-authentication

I am using laravel 5.5, want to record Last Login (date time)and Last Login IP on each successful login.but its not updating.

**LoginController:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $user->update([
            'last_login_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
            'last_login_ip' => $request->getClientIp()
        ]);
    }
}
```

**User Model:**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'first_name','last_name', 'email', 'password','phone','user_type','last_login_at',
    'last_login_ip',
];
```

Comment: did you add last_login_at and last_login_ip to your protected $fillable array in App\User ?

Comment: yes. i have added

Comment: when u  add a dd($user) in the method, does the dump shows or nothing happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recording last login information is useful and you can easily save and update the last login time and IP address of the client.

You can achieve this in several ways but I am gonna show you very simple and effective technique, just add the below-shown method to the login Controller

```
function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $user->last_login = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
        $user->last_login_ip = $request->getClientIp();
        $user->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Did you imported carbon package?

Anyway to implement this i think https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events is an elegant way.

Inside app\Providers\EventServiceProvider.php write below code

```
   protected $listen = [

      'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogin',
       ],
 ];
```

Create a Listener Inside app\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogin.php

```
namespace App\Listeners;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;

class LogSuccessfulLogin {

  /**
   * Create the event listener.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function __construct(){


  }

 /**
  * Handle the event.
  *
  * @param  Login $event
  * @throws \Exception
  */

  public function handle(Login $event){
    $user = $event->user;

    $user->last_login_ip = request()->getClientIp();
    $user->save();

  }
}
```

Just update the handle() as you wish. Import carbon package here & update last_login_at.

Comment: Welcome @ArunJaganathan  :)

Comment: Hello worked like a charm. Could you please advice how to add last login date with similar process ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to record the last visit of the user, firstly run this command

```
php artisan make:middleware LastVisit
```

Then add this line to the end of the middlewareGroups array (App\Http\Kernel.php)

```
\App\Http\Middleware\LastVisit::class,
```

Lastly change your LastVisit middleware. (I assume that you have a last_visit column in your users table)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LastVisit
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        $user = Auth::User();
        $user->timestamps = false;
        $user->last_visit = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
        $user->save();

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

This works with remember me token and social logins too.